# Java - Retrieving data from Postgresql, show them and edit them

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql

Maybe a dumb/newbie question, but I've no idea about how to proceed: I'm implemeting a web phone book, with just name, surname and phone number as inputs.
At the moment I'm able to perform correctly a query on a postgresql database, with a jsp page that show data in a table. In the same page I've to show a page-link/button/whatever for editing one of the row, but I don't know how to do it; more in detail, I don't know how to select the data that I need to send to an edit jsp page (for example).
At the moment my (not working) solution is to show data into a form (with data as default input values), and for each row I show a radio button and a submit button: I've tried to set the data as values of the radio button but when I send it to the edit page, the request.getParameter on the radio button fails (null pointer).
Here some code:

search.jsp (this is how I fill the form)

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="surname" value="<%=rs.getString("surname")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<%=rs.getString("phone")%>"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radio" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>; <%=rs.getString("surname")%>; <%=rs.getString("phone")%>"><input type="submit" name="name" value="Edit"></td>
</tr>
```

This is how I try to get radio parameters:

```
    String radioInput = request.getParameter("radio");
    String[] tmp = radioInput.split("; ");
    String name=tmp[0];
    String surname=tmp[1];
    String phone=tmp[2];
```

I'm quite sure that it is possible to do it with javascript, but I'm not good with it.
I'm also quite sure that there is a more raffinate solution.
I wonder if it is possible to scan (in some way) the values of the line in which the radio is checked, to store them in context or in whatever accessible place.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks.

Marco Dalena

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Send the user to a form allowing to edit one row, or allow the user to edit all the rows at once?

Comment: [This](http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/) seems to a fairly good example of a basic CRUD application. Should get you started.

Comment: @JBNizet The user must have the chance to choose a row and then edit it;

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, it seems a very good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the code should do. Each Person in the table should have a primary key, which identifies it uniquely. Let's call it `id`.

The first page should be implemented as a `ListPersons` servlet. This servlet would read rows from the database using a query, create a Person instance for each row, populate a `List<Person>`, and store it in a request attribute. Then the servlet should forward the request and response (using the request dispatcher) to the `listPersons.jsp` JSP.

The JSP should then use the JSTL to iterate over the list of persons and display each person in an HTML table row.

Each row should contain a link to the person edit page. The URL of this link should look like

```
/myApp/editPerson?id=<theIDOfThePersonToEdit>
```

Such a link can easily be generated using the JSTL:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/editPerson'>
             <c:param name='id' value='${person.id}'/>
         </c:url>">Click here to edit the person</a>
```

You should have a second servlet mapped to `/editPerson`. This servlet would get the ID of the person to edit from the `id` request parameter, and would use a SQL query to retrieve the person information. It would create an instance of Person with this information a,d store it in a request attribute. It would then dispatch to `editPerson.jsp`.

This JSP would then generate a form, pre-populated with the person stored in the request attribute. This form would contain a hidden field containing the ID of the edited person. The form would post to a servlet (which could be the same or another one), which would validate the information, update the database row, and the redirect (using `response.sendRedirect()`) to, for example, the `ListPersons` servlet URL.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what was posted in the comment at my question. It has been really helpfull.